# Nested For Loop in R to iterate between columns

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to generate a dataset in which I keep the changing the first column every three rows later and as I change the first column, the second and third column change with it as well. Example given below. I'm a little confused as to how I can achieve this with the nested for loop.

```r
df = NULL 
   for (CDRID in 1:3) 
{ 
for (STARTDATE in 20200517:20200519) 
{ 
for (PRIIDENTITY in 4:6) 
{
    df1 = rbind(df, data.frame  ( "CDR_ID"=CDRID, "START_DATE"=STARTDATE, "PRI_IDENTITY"=PRIIDENTITY)) }}}
```

[image: Expected dataset]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Iteratively growing data.frames works in concept but gets really slow: each time you call `rbind`, it makes a complete copy of all rows. That means that if you loop through this nine times (as your loops show here), the first batch is duplicated in memory eight times (imagine how this scales). It is much better to add them to a `list` and then combine them at the end with one of `do.call(rbind, L)`, `dplyr::bind_rows(L)`, or `data.table::rbindlist(L)`. (See chapter 2, "Growing objects", within the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).)

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, START_DATE=20200517:20200519, PRI_IDENTITY=4:6)
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each=3),]
#     ID START_DATE PRI_IDENTITY
# 1    1   20200517            4
# 1.1  1   20200517            4
# 1.2  1   20200517            4
# 2    2   20200518            5
# 2.1  2   20200518            5
# 2.2  2   20200518            5
# 3    3   20200519            6
# 3.1  3   20200519            6
# 3.2  3   20200519            6
```

A thought: `20200517:20200519`, where I'm making an assumption that these are intended to be dates. This is fragile in that it doesn't know about wrapping days between months. In R, it might be better to use proper `Date` objects. With that, try:

```r
> df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, START_DATE=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-05-17"), as.Date("2020-05-19"), by="days"), PRI_IDENTITY=4:6)
Browse[2]> df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each=3),]
    ID START_DATE PRI_IDENTITY
1    1 2020-05-17            4
1.1  1 2020-05-17            4
1.2  1 2020-05-17            4
2    2 2020-05-18            5
2.1  2 2020-05-18            5
2.2  2 2020-05-18            5
3    3 2020-05-19            6
3.1  3 2020-05-19            6
3.2  3 2020-05-19            6
```

As akrun suggested, if you are using (or amenable to using) packages from the tidyverse, then instead of the `rep(seq_len(...` part, you can do

```r
# df <- data.frame(...)
tidyr::uncount(df, 3)
```

Comment: Another option is `df %>% uncount(3)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help
Also thank you for pointing out that the date should increment in terms of specified date time format. 
Using seq_len solved the issue.